# View controller is not rotating in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

My app works fine in ios 6.But when i upgrade my app to ios 7, view controller is not rotating.I have set rootviewcontroller to mainviewcontroller.
self.window.rootViewController=mainViewcontroller;
What change in ios 7 make my app to not rotating..?

Comment: I have a similar problem.

Comment: Can we have more information? Are you using the correct rotation delegate methods in your mainViewController? Can you copy-paste the code block you reference rather than re-typing? Can you also paste code from your `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method? Did you set the supported interface orientations in xcode and/or in that method?

Comment: actually problem has been solved but we have to change many of code lines thats why i cant paste correct answer here..thanks for your support. briefly some issue was related to notification was there. In iOS 7 there are some change in notification generation.

Comment: @maruti i am facing such issues for Video. Please share your knowledge and answer your own question. Waiting for reply .Thanks.

Comment: actually there will be many issue which may cause this.1.
1.Set viewcontroller to rootyviewcontroller instead of addsubview.
2.In our project two window was added.this cause only rotate one window.Due to change in notification.
3.If you use windowlevel property in your project than try to change  it to alert level.

Answer (score 1):

This the code I have tested in xcode 4.6 and xcode5-DP6

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;//self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In ViewController I have inserted below methods for testing

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"rotated");
}
```

By using above code there is nothing  problem in rotation. Its perfectly rotating in all directions.

**Check your orientation methods to overcome this problem or post some code snippet.**

Note: I have created sample appication in Xcode4.6.

Comment: Xcode 4.6 does not have the capability to compile for iOS7 which is what the OP asked about. You could try this experiment again in Xcode5 and update.